# How to determine all homomorphisms from a quadratic field to $\mathbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K_D= \mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-D)$ where $D \in \mathbb Q$. I was asked to determine all homomorphism from $K_D$ to $ \mathbb C$. First if $D$ is a square of some rational numbers, the quotient will just be the field of rational numbers. The second case is when the sqaure root of $D$ is either irrational number or the complex number. For the first case I suspect the only ring homomorphism is  plus/minus identity or multiplication by $\pm i$ (Multiplicative identity should match). For the second case, I don't know what to do because I am not sure how the image of $a+b \sqrt d$ should be look like. Can anyone provide some hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def \C {{\mathbb C}}\def \Q {{\mathbb Q}}$

First of all, I should correct your first statement...

If $D = 0$, then $K_D$ has zero divisors - $X^2 = 0$ - and so is not a field.

Likewise, if  $D =u^2$ and $u\in \Q$, with $u\ne 0$, then $K_D$ is isomorphic, as rings, to $\Q^2$, under the isomorphism
 $$ a + b X \mapsto ( a + b u, a - bu).$$

You have to check the map is an isomorphism: in particular, that it's a ring homorphism, and  if $x, y \in \Q$, that you can find $a, b\in \Q$ such that 
$ x = a + bu$, and $y = a- bu$ - the latter is obviously just linear algebra. 
In any event, if you accept the above, again $K_{u^2}$ is not a field: for instance,  $$(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0).$$

To answer the actual question: a ring homomorphism from $K_D\rightarrow \C$ takes $1$ to $1$ and $X$ to some number $u\in \C$, and is $\Q$-linear. Hence any ($\Q$-linear, let alone ring) homomorphism is of the form - and is defined by -
$$ a + b X \mapsto a + b u,$$
where $a, b\in \Q$.

What are the possible $u$?  A ring homormophism respects multiplication: hence $X^2\mapsto u^2$. On the other hand, in $K_D$, $X^2 = D$. So, in $\C$, we must choose $u$ so that $u^2 = D$. You have to check - general theory, of course, see below - that that is the only requirement for the above linear map to define a ring homomorphsm.

Hence, there is a bijection between the sets of ring homomorphisms $K_D\rightarrow\C$ and the set of $u \in \C$ such that $u^2 = D$. So if $D=0$, there is only one homomorpism; otherwise there are two.

"General theory": suppose $p(X)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. For an arbitrary $\Q$-algebra $A$, (where being a $\Q$-algebra means  that $\Q$ sits inside as a subring of $A$), then there is a bijection between the set of ring homorphisms $$\Q[X]/(p(X))\rightarrow A$$
and the set of $a \in A$ such that $p(a) = 0$ - i.e., any and every such homomorphism is of the form $$ X \mapsto a.$$
For example if $A= \Q[\epsilon]$, where $\epsilon^2 = 0$, then there are two homomorphisms $ \Q[X]/X^2 \rightarrow A$: i.e., $X \mapsto \epsilon$, and $X\mapsto -\epsilon$.

In the second example, above with $D = u^2$, $u\in \Q$, $u\ne 0$, and $A=\Q^2$, $a = (u,-u)$ corresponded to the isomorphism, but you could have chosen any of the four $a = (\pm u,\pm u)$ to have a ring homomorphism, although only two lead to isomorphisms.

Comment: Rereading your question, I see that you asked for "hints" - I think I went too far! If so, sorry - if you are turning something in, you should acknowledge outside references...

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually I did not know the general theorem. It is very nice to know the big picture. This really give me many insights on the problem!